# Q3DBars with vertical labels in just one corner, possible?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, data-visualization, qwidget

This is the plot

[image]

And this is the code

.pro

```
QT      += core gui widgets datavisualization
TEMPLATE = app
SOURCES += main.cpp mainwindow.cpp
HEADERS += mainwindow.h
```

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.cpp"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QMainWindow>

#include <QtDataVisualization/Q3DBars>
using namespace QtDataVisualization;

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent) {
    resize(800,600);
    Q3DBars *graph = new Q3DBars;
    setCentralWidget(QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph));
    graph->scene()->activeCamera()->setCameraPosition(30,30);
    graph->activeTheme()->setGridLineColor(Qt::red);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow(){}
```

Can I have labels for vertical axis (values axis) in just one corner, instead of two?

Answer (score 0):

To add custom labels:

```
auto graph = new Q3DBars;
auto container = QWidget::createWindowContainer(graph);
setCentralWidget(container);

auto label = new QCustom3DLabel;
graph->addCustomItem(label);
label->setText("text");
label->setPosition(QVector3D(0,0.5,0));
label->setTextColor(Qt::red);
label->setScaling(QVector3D(1,1,1));
```